# Native-base SwipeRow - Can't add onPress/TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to add TouchableOpacity to SwipeRow component of native-base, but it doesn't work.
If I add TouchableOpacity inside my 'body' item, nothing is show on the list.
With my current code, the touch only works if I click on very edge of each item (like the line that divide each item)....in the item center nothing happens. The swipe is working fine.
This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Content,
  Text,
  Button,
  Icon,
  SwipeRow,
  Left,
  Body,
  Footer
} from "native-base";
import { FlatList, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ArchiveItem from "./components/archiveItem";

import styles from "./styles";
import { translate } from "../../i18n";
var i18n_opt = { scope: "archive" };

class Archive extends Component {
  rows = [];
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.rows = [];
  }

  _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("teste")}>
        <SwipeRow
          style={styles.swipe}
          ref={c => {
            this.rows.push({ ref: c, id: item.id });
          }}
          rightOpenValue={-65}
          onRowOpen={() => {
            this.rows.forEach(ref => {
              if (ref.id != item.id) {
                ref.ref._root.closeRow();
              }
            });
          }}
          body={<ArchiveItem item={item} />}
          right={
            <Button
              danger
              onPress={() => alert("Trash")}
              style={styles.swipebuttons}
            >
              <Icon active name="trash" />
            </Button>
          }
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { archive } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button
              transparent
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}
            >
              <Icon name="menu" />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>{translate("title", { ...i18n_opt })}</Title>
          </Body>
        </Header>

        <Content>
          <FlatList
            data={archive}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          />
        </Content>

        <Footer>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              this.rows.forEach(ref => {
                ref.ref._root.closeRow();
              });
            }}
          >
            <Text>teste</Text>
          </Button>
        </Footer>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    archive: state.archive
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(Archive);
```

And the item:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Text, TouchableHighlight, View} from 'react-native';

import {
    Grid,
    Row,
    Col
} from 'native-base';

import styles from "../styles";


class ArchiveItem extends Component {

    render() {

        const item = this.props.item;

        return (

                <Grid>                                        
                    <Col size={90}>                    
                        <Row>
                            <Col size={67}><Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 14}}>Jonis</Text></Col>
                            <Col size={33}><Text style={{fontSize: 10, alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginRight: 3}}>Total time: 00:00:01</Text></Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Laps</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Last Lap</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Best lap</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>Best time</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemHeaderText,styles.itemAlignRight, {marginRight: 5}]}>Dif</Text></Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemValueText}>30</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText, {fontWeight: 'bold'}]}>01:02:03</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemValueText}>8</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText, { color: '#90db18', fontWeight: 'bold' }]}>01:01:01</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText,styles.itemAlignRight, {marginRight: 5}]}>+1s</Text></Col>
                        </Row>                            
                    </Col>                    
                </Grid>   

        );

    }


}


export default ArchiveItem;
```

Comment: Just wrap body prop of SwipeRow with TouchableOpacity, worked for me

Comment: @Oleg, brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `SwipeRow` wrapped by `TouchableOpacity`, wrap `ArchiveItem` with `TouchableOpacity`.